# can not access parent fields on a master detail

Tags: apex, soql, query, developer-console, execute-anonymous

I need to an object and modify it's parent if condition are fullfiled but i'm encoutering an wierd behavior: in my SOQL the __r.field doesn't retrieve the fields values:

Below my anonymous code:

```
list<FLU_PaymentDeadline__c> pdl = [Select FLU_Contract__r.Name, 
FLU_Contract__r.FLU_ReviewAutoPay__c, SystemModstamp, FLU_PaymentMeans__c
                                    FROM FLU_PaymentDeadline__c 
                                    where FLU_PaymentMeans__c = 'CB'];
system.debug(pdl);
```

My debug is the following
[image]

**I can see the contract even if I did not query it and cannot see any field on the contract.**

I tried with the query editor the same query:

[image]

Here i got what i want.

Can anybody else encoutered this kind of behavior already?
I did check my profiles right in case it had something to do with it but I got access on all fields required.

Comment: What if you do ```system.debug(pdl. FLU_Contract__r);``` ? It could be just a debug that does not show relationship, but they are actually queried

Comment: @kurunve it says :"Variable does not exist: FLU_Contract__r" I tryed aswel debugging just the field (FLU_Contract__r.FLU_ReviewAutoPay__c) same error.

Comment: There is a typo on my snippet, it should be without space in between -- ```system.debug(pdl.FLU_Contract__r);```

Comment: Yeah i saw but still not working

Comment: @kurunve you were right in your first answer:
"It could be just a debug that does not show relationship, but they are actually queried"
I answered my question below you can check it. Thanks

Comment: Please check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160434/accessing-the-parent-sobject-from-the-child-sobject) for better understanding.

Comment: For a detailed explanation, check this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160434/accessing-the-parent-sobject-from-the-child-sobject

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the answer, and it's a stupid one...

It appears that as I query a list, if I debug it I don't have the debug information of the parent. I have to debug element by element to see the parent relationship.

```
list<FLU_PaymentDeadline__c> pdl = [Select FLU_Contract__r.Name, 
FLU_Contract__r.FLU_ReviewAutoPay__c, SystemModstamp, FLU_PaymentMeans__c
                                    FROM FLU_PaymentDeadline__c 
                                    where FLU_PaymentMeans__c = 'CB'];
system.debug(pdl[0]);
```

Will show the parents fields.

Answer (score 0):

If Profile level FLS and CRUD accesses are given, you should check the sharing settings of the contract object.

Comment: Did that aswell, sharing settings are Public Read/Write